# Unable to reach the login screen after update in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, boot, gnome

After I performed an update in Arch Linux with

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

I shut down the laptop. Upon restarting it, I was presented with a black screen with a blinking cursor, instead of the login screen. I am still able to reach Gnome GUI by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get into `tty2` followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to reach the login screen. Once I do that everything works flawlessly, as expected.

I'm using GNOME version 3.36.3 with Xorg on `Linux 5.7.7-arch1-1`

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your installation was successful? Usually a blinking cursor in the upper left corner of the screen indicates that your BIOS could not find any operating system installed on your hard drive. A plain black screen or scrambled screen indicates you have an issue with a video driver, or either the wrong one or a lack of one to be more specific.

Comment: There is no question whether the installation was successful.  As you can see in my post am able to use it just fine. Also regarding the video driver, I don't believe that's the case since because I would get a (as you said) "plain black screen" AFTER the login screen. My issue, I believe is related to gdm but am not sure what exactly...

Comment: Ok great look for any issue with grub.may be you'll need to get your system into maintance mode